# woocommerce product orderby ID with custom order(Not ASC OR DESC)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

i have used shortcode 
'[products ids="1,3,2" orderby="ID"]'
to get the products with id 1,3,2. on page display, product showing as 3,2,1 if using order parameter it will display in ASC order or DESC order. but my order should be 1,3,2. how can i achieve it.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
[products ids="1,3,2" orderby="menu_order"]
```

Then try the order attribute

Comment: Rich "menu_order" works on if we add order number in page attributes.

Comment: I think thats probably the only way to do exactly what you need to do and with only three products is viable.

Answer (score 0):

[products ids="1,3,2" orderby="post__in"]

The post__in attribute seems to accomplish this.

Answer (score -1):

To order products in the order you want, first collect your products id, then use:
[products number="12" orderby="id" id="10,18"]

Change the number by the number of products you want to display, and the IDs by yours.

It works with categories too:
[product_categories number="12" orderby="id" id="10,18"]

Comment: This does not work, firstly it needs to be 'ids'= and not 'id'=.  And secondly it does not order them by ID