# 'Order by' specified order in Woocommerce shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, shortcode

I am currently using the **shortcode**:

```
[product_categories ids="135, 214, 244, 1958, 72, 205, 43, 559, 73, 1033, 69, 2009, 1365, 1250, 462, 346, 1649, 1344, 1379, 1373" orderby="id"]
```

to display **Woocommerce** product categories on a Wordpress site. It works, but I need the categories to be displayed in the order that they're listed in the ids quotations. I know of `orderby="name"`, **"date"**, and **"id"**, and none of those will work for this particular task unless you know of any nifty hacks that involve them.

Any Ideas? Thanks

Comment: Have you taken a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28736590/woocommerce-product-orderby-id-with-custom-ordernot-asc-or-desc) ?

Comment: Yes, I've got it open in another tab actually. Unfortunately Paolo's suggestions didn't work and the "menu-order" option doesn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't solved the issue but I'm going to post this work around as an answer in case anyone else is struggling with this.

Just re-ordered the sub-categories in the order you want them displayed manually. Do this with the **drag-and-drop method** in **WooCommerce > products > categories**. Then in your short-code, write:

```
[product_categories parent="*your parent category id*" ids="*the sub-category ids you want displayed*" hide_empty="0"]
```

This will display your specified sub categories in the order that you put them in with the drag and drop.

**Note:** 
If you want to hide categories without any products in them remove the 'hide_empty' portion of the short-code. Also when displaying multiple sub categories, remember that the ids are separated by commas. ie: ids="1, 2, 3"

If anyone knows the short-code solution please post/comment, because the drag and drop method is very time consuming when you have hundreds of categories.

Answer (score 1):

The [shortcode](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/#product-category-shortcodes) now has an attribute `orderby = "include"` to order by the ids.